# Need help fixing random number

Tags: python, random, while-loop, dice

I'm learning Python and was working on the random dice throw. When I run it, it repeats the same number that is first shown after asked if you want to play again. I need help finding where I'm going wrong here.

I've tried moving code around and also putting different varieties of the code. I'm just stumped.

```
import sys
import random
import time


greeting = "Welcome to my Dice Game!"
roll = "Lets roll this die!"
die = random.randint(0, 6)

print(greeting)
time.sleep(2)

answer = input("Want to play?")

while answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
    print(roll)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(die)
    answer = input("Want to play again?")
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

This is what I get:

```
Welcome to my Dice Game!
Want to play?yes
Lets roll this die!
5
Want to play again?yes
Lets roll this die!
5
Want to play again?y
Lets roll this die!
5
```

Comment: `die = random.randint(0, 6)` needs to be inside your loop otherwise the value is just set once at the start.

Comment: You called `randint` *once*, and generated one random number. Every time you want to generate another, you need to call it again.

Comment: Just move `die = random.randint(0, 6)` to right above `print(die)`

Comment: Also, it should be `die = random.randint(1, 6)` unless you have a seven sided die.

Comment: Appreciate it guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recompute the value of the dice each time in your loop like:

```
import sys
import random
import time


greeting = "Welcome to my Dice Game!"
roll = "Lets roll this die!"


print(greeting)
time.sleep(2)

answer = input("Want to play?")

while answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
    print(roll)
    time.sleep(2)
    die = random.randint(0, 6) # recompute it here instead
    print(die)
    answer = input("Want to play again?")
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Shinnnobuuu No problem! If this solved your problem its standard practice to click the check mark by the post to mark it as an accepted answer. This signals other users to read the post when they encounter the same error. When you hit 15 rep you can upvote helpful questions/answers as well!

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `die = random.randint(0, 6)`, what you're telling Python is "Use the `random.randint()` function to pick a random integer between 1 and 6, and then set the variable named `die` equal to the integer that got chosen".  Once that's done, the rest of your code doesn't do anything to update the value of `die`.  This means `print(die)` within the loop is just going to keep printing whatever value it was initially given.  In other words, the command `die = random.randint(0, 6)` *doesn't* mean "Re-run the command `random.randint(0, 6)` and get another random number each and every time I refer to `die`".  Rather, `die` is just some variable with a specific, constant value.

Since `random.randint()` is what does the actual number generation, one way to keep updating `die` is to simply move the command you have outside of the loop to the inside of the loop:

```
while answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
    print(roll)
    die = random.randint(0, 6) # Generate a new random number, then assign it to 'die'
    time.sleep(2)
    print(die)
    answer = input("Want to play again?")
```

In fact, if you aren't really doing anything with the number other than printing it, you could forget using a variable altogether and just stick the `random.randint()` command inside of your `print` command:

```
while answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
    print(roll)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(random.randint(0, 6))
    answer = input("Want to play again?")
```

Comment: Thanks helped a lot to understand my mess up. really appreciate it!